# How to dynamically pass on a scalar value in SQL temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a current query which is as following

```
DECLARE @start BIGINT =2019, @end BIGINT =2020

DECLARE @yeartable table ( yr BIGINT)

WHILE (@start <= @end)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @yeartable
        SELECT @start

    SET @start = @start + 1
END
```

All I want to do is to pass on the `@start` and `@end` values dynamically from another query

For `@start` I will use

```
 SELECT MIN(fiscal_year)
 FROM a.b
```

For `@end` I will use

```
SELECT MAX(fiscal_year)
FROM a.b
```

Is this possible at all? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This sort of thing is better solved with a numbers table rather than a loop. Such a table than easily accepts a parameterized `WHERE`, or you can use a table-valued function.

Comment: @JeroenMostert can you please give me an example query please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I found the answer

```
        DECLARE 
@start BIGINT =(SELECT MIN(fiscal_year)
FROM
a.b), 
@end BIGINT = (SELECT MAX(fiscal_year) 
FROM
a.b])

DECLARE @yeartable table ( yr BIGINT)

while (@start <= @end)
begin
    insert into @yeartable
    select @start

    set @start = @start+1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the variables this way:

```
SELECT @start = MIN(fiscal_year)
    FROM a.b

SELECT @end = MAX(fiscal_year)
    FROM a.b
```